# Javascript - iterate through table row and edit cell style

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, loops, iteration

Any idea why the below code is not working? My goal is to iterate through each row and apply a style to the cell depending on the value. For some reason my code only updates the top row.

```
function blah()
{
    var alternativeAptTimeBit = document.getElementById('alternativeAptTime');
/*  var alternativeAptDateBit = document.getElementById('alternativeAptDate');
    var alternativeAptDoctorBit = document.getElementById('alternativeAptDoctor');*/

    var table = document.getElementById("tbl-appointment-requests");
    var rows = table.rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (alternativeAptTimeBit.innerHTML === "0")
        {
            alternativeAptTimeBit.className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
            alternativeAptTimeBit.innerHTML = null;
        } else {
            alternativeAptTimeBit.className="glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
            alternativeAptTimeBit.innerHTML = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if needs condtional not assignment, === instead of =

Comment: @MattR You're correct, but that as not solved the problem.

Comment: Also, you aren't updating the rows. You're updating the one specific element. You need to update your alternativeAptBit variable in the loop or use rows[i]

Comment: @MattR do you have an example?

Comment: At the start of your function you set alternativeAptTimeBit to the document.getElementById('alternativeAptTime') element. In each step of the loop you update alternativeAptTimeBit which will always be the original element. Look up any javascript tutorials on loops.

Comment: sorted, cheers bro x @MattR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job seems to to the job.

```
function blah() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tbl-appointment-requests");

  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

      if (col.id === "alternativeAptTime") {
        if (col.id.innerHTML === "0") {
          col.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
          col.innerHTML = null;
        } else {
          col.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
          col.innerHTML = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```